# Does anything happen if you don't obey the commands to press buttons?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

At one point in the Stanley Parable, the game asks you to press different buttons and then usually makes a joke about you afterwards.

An example is:

> PLEASE PRESS 'Z' TO BE AT WORK IN THE MORNING.

I've waited a couple minutes to see if anything will ever happen on one of these button push screens, but I'm not ready to wait around for longer to see if anything ever happens.

Does anything ever happen if you refuse to hit the required button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't press the button and wait for the morning, the hour hand will stop. The minute and second hands will keep going, but the hour hand will stop at a quarter to 6:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Artur, welcome to Arcade. Please upload your images using the 'Image' tool. These images seem to be broken, and without them your answer doesn't add much and may be deleted.

Comment: Hey Artur! I've taken the liberty of cropping your images and editing your post a bit. Images are helpful in answers, but a full-desktop screenshot is typically not necessary. You can screenshot a window by focusing it and pressing `Alt`+`PrtSc`. Alternatively, you can crop them. Also, when sharing from dropbox, make sure you directly share the public link and not the image preview page.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, sat there for 2 hours (Not kidding) not a thing... though... if the 4 hour baby thing was true, then maybe there IS something, though I am 99% sure that there isn't. Have fun!

Comment: #Savethebaby #Savethepuppy #Savethefuture http://www.twitch.tv/futuremangaming/v/21469398, Skip to close to the end to know for sure.